# как собрать x32 приложения в x64 системе - с#

Tags: c#, windows, x86-64

мне нужно собрать x32 приложения  в x64 системе в visual studio 2019 ,
или есть програма которая переделывает x64 битное приложения под x32 ??

Comment: В Configuration Manager укажите не AnyCPU, а x86 - по идее если ничего специфически x64 нет - просто соберётся без проблем.

Comment: [Сборка приложений](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-building-an-application?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В платформе решений выбери *Any CPU*, либо разверни список, нажми "*Диспетчер конфигураций*"
[image: Диспетчер конфигураций]

далее *Платформа* → *Создать* и выбираешь нужную тебе разрядность.
[image: Изменение разрядности]

После этих действий в платформе решений появиться новый пункт.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]